# Cannot build my parameter string without getting a new line

Tags: java, android, base64

Hello im having an issue with my url connection, it adds a . to my url, and when i try to log the data it makes a new line at the places it makes the .

It happens when i try to build the url string with parameters, if I write the entire string my self it works as it should, but when i combine the parameters it fails

```
  String parameters = "?game=eyJDcmVhdGVkIjoxNTA1MTEzNTAzLCJJZCI6MSwiTmFtZSI6IkFjdHVyYSJ9&player=eyJJZCI6MSwiTGFzdEFjdGl2aXR5IjoxNTA1MTEzNTAzLCJOYW1lIjoiMzU2NzEzMDcwODY1NzEwIn0=";
  Log.e("TEST1",parameters);

  String arg0 = Encryption.encryptData(args[0]);
  String arg1 = Encryption.encryptData(args[1]);    
  parameters = "?game=" + arg0 + "&player=" + arg1;
  Log.e("TEST2",parameters);

  parameters = "?game=" + Encryption.encryptData(args[0]) + "&player=" + Encryption.encryptData(args[1]);
  Log.e("TEST3",parameters);
```

LOGS:

```
  09-11 11:49:57.971 30360-31259/dk.actura.games.flagit E/TEST1: ?game=eyJDcmVhdGVkIjoxNTA1MTEzNTAzLCJJZCI6MSwiTmFtZSI6IkFjdHVyYSJ9&player=eyJJZCI6MSwiTGFzdEFjdGl2aXR5IjoxNTA1MTEzNTAzLCJOYW1lIjoiMzU2NzEzMDcwODY1NzEwIn0=
  09-11 11:49:57.971 30360-31259/dk.actura.games.flagit E/TEST2: ?game=eyJDcmVhdGVkIjoxNTA1MTEzNTAzLCJJZCI6MSwiTmFtZSI6IkFjdHVyYSJ9
                                                                   &player=eyJJZCI6MSwiTGFzdEFjdGl2aXR5IjoxNTA1MTEzNTAzLCJOYW1lIjoiMzU2NzEzMDcwODY1NzEw
                                                                   In0=
  09-11 11:49:57.971 30360-31259/dk.actura.games.flagit E/TEST3: ?game=eyJDcmVhdGVkIjoxNTA1MTEzNTAzLCJJZCI6MSwiTmFtZSI6IkFjdHVyYSJ9
                                                                   &player=eyJJZCI6MSwiTGFzdEFjdGl2aXR5IjoxNTA1MTEzNTAzLCJOYW1lIjoiMzU2NzEzMDcwODY1NzEw
                                                                   In0=
```

The encryption so far is just a normal base64 url safe

```
public static String encryptData(String s) {
    if (s == null) return "";
    return Base64.encodeToString(s.getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently the Base64.URL_SAFE is not as urlsafe as it sounds, i found using NO_WRAP to fix my problem

```
public static String encryptData(String s) {
    if (s == null) return "";
    return Base64.encodeToString(s.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```